# Eclipse runs old code instead of updated one

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I've got a weird issue, and nowhere to find a solution.
I'm currently working on a web java test project on eclipse. Nothing particular at the moment: a simple java servlet that sends a request object (with attributes) to a jsp.
Attributes are a couple of String variables i've set myself.

Problem is: no matter which string value i update, when i run/debug the app, eclipse will still use the old data value.
And i've tried to build automatically the project, still doing it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clean and build you project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
It was actually a problem in the project build path. As this is an imported project, the JRE version was different from the version i'm using on my machine right now.

Solution:

Right Click on project-> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Librairies -> Remove old JRE -> Add Library -> Add new JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project: <kbd>Project</kbd> -> <kbd>Clean</kbd>